# The right way of setting <a href=“”> when it's a local file

Tags: html

```
<a href="file://{{files[i]}}">{{names[i]}}</a>
```

This is the one I am using for giving file path in my html template.
`files[i]` is `/Users/../../file1.txt` and `names[i]` is file1.txt. In my webpage I am getting file1, file2 etc. And when I point my cursor to any of them, then the correct file path shows at the bottom. But when I try to click it is not redirecting to the file location. But when I copy the link address and paste it in a new tab, I am able to open the txt file. Can someone please give me a solution why this is happening.

Comment: So, you then end up getting "file:///Users/..." with three forward slashes?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use relative paths instead?

Comment: Please provide an example of the exact HTML you are generating.

Comment: Did you try changing it so that `files[i]` is `C:/Users/...`?